# How to skip counting null or empty cells inside MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

I have this database table where one column is email and in front of that have different other columns used to store data for that email. When I use mysqli_num_rows() function it counts the empty fields as well.

How should I modify this query such that I don't get empty cells counted

```
<?php
$query = "SELECT * FROM user_info WHERE email='$email'";
$data = mysqli_query($connec,$query);
$total = mysqli_num_rows($data);

echo "Registered for ". $total. " Modules";
?>
```

Thanking in anticipation

Comment: Your question makes no sense. `mysqli_num_rows()` counts the number of rows matched by your query. In your example, the email address either matches or it doesn't. If it doesn't it's not selected and won't be included in your count.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
"SELECT * FROM user_info WHERE email='$email' and UID IS NOT NULL AND SENT_DATE IS NOT NULL AND TOTAL_BOUNCE_COUNT IS NOT NULL;"
```

For each column for which a NULL make the record invalid, put in that syntax to exclude records that have a null from the count.  Of course I just made up column names in my answer.  You'd put the column names in your table in place of SENT_DATE/TOTAL_BOUNCE_COUNT/UID.

Comment: Spot on, thank you soooooooooooooooooo much <3 <3 .. you solved a big dilemma for me.